# buttonBarStyle requires API level 11

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, android-appcompat

I am trying this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/alert_banner"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    android:background="@color/holo_red_light"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="1dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alert_banner_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="#EEEEEE" 
        android:text="@string/offline_warning_text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the style lines are giving me this error:

> ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle requires API level 11 (current min is 10)

Not sure why this is, I am using app compat lib.  Can I use app compat styles?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/johnkil/2471342)

Use this for API10:

```
<!--
  A button bar is a set of buttons at the bottom of an activity.
  An example is an AlertDialog with OK/Cancel buttons.

  Note that something similar can be accomplished using a
  split action bar and text-only action buttons, but this is an
  alternate presentation that's often preferred.
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
        android:dividerPadding="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="One" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="Two" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And use your code for API11+

Comment: What happens when I want to support 10+ in the same app?  Also when you use appcompat you don't get the styles?  Why do I need to implement this?

Comment: it's for the same app, using resource qualifiers. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html